# Error of pdflatex in LyX

Tags: errors, lyx

I prepared a document, which was entirely okay, until some changes have been introduced (perhaps associated with the use of bibliography, or `breqn`/`mh` package, or `split` environment). They lead to the error of `pdflatex` commands, including preview and export: "Error while exporting format". Details weren't specified by the editor (even in tmp directory).

After reloading LyX, it became more specific, saying that "the directory path to the document cannot contain spaces." Moving to other locations, without spaces, do not help.

Then I installed 2.0.6 and replaced MiKTeX with TeXLive, nothing changed: LyX can't create a preview or pdf of this file.

LaTeX log says nothing. I've done research around the Web, and no solution suits.

Is it possible to find out what settings or code cause such problems?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was due to one of citations, in which I've used "Text before" parameter and inserted a n-dash in it. LyX put it in the code as `\citet[pp. 5–10]{author2000title}` and that prevented LyX even from launching verification procedure, i.e., it couldn't report that was the mistake.

Sorry for bothering you.